# I how I add a link to userstory for the FormattedID column?

Tags: rally

I have extended the the App2.0 example grid with freedom data to include formatted ID too but it appears as TEXT only not a link. 
I get the formatted ID using 
FormattedID: record.get('FormattedID')

to get the url , I try record.get('FormattedID')._ref but it doesn't work.

any one can help?I do want to use freedom data as I have a custom column but also want the formatted ID and parent field to be links.

Thanks In advance
Tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following column configuration to your grid's config:

```
{
    header: 'Formatted ID',
    renderer: function(value, metaData, record) {
        var linkBuilder = Ext.create('Rally.util.DetailLinkBuilder').inFrame(true);
        return linkBuilder.build(record.get('FormattedID'), record.get('_ref'), false);
    }
}
```

Please note that the DetailLinkBuilder class is marked as private in the SDK documentation because its interface has not been finalized yet. It is likely that its interface will be changed in a future version of the SDK, and you will need to update your code when you upgrade to a newer version of the SDK.