# SDK2: Links in Rally Grids and column width

Tags: rally

I'm displaying a link to a defect in a Rally Grid in the simple way:

```
columnCfgs: ['FormattedID', 'Name', ...]
```

This creates a link to the defect, just like it should.  But the column width is way too big.  But if I do the following, I loose the link:

```
columnCfgs: [{dataIndex: 'FormattedID', width: 50, text:'ID'}', 'Name', ...]
```

Is there a convenient xtype I can use to adjust the width, but still have a link to my defect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not an easy way to do this right now.  We are going to fix this before we GA the SDK 2.0.  For now here is a workaround:

```
Ext.define('DefectGridApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',

    launch: function() {
        Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'Defect',
            success: function(model) {

                //Get the default field config
                var field = model.getField('FormattedID');
                var fieldConfig = Rally.ui.grid.FieldColumnFactory.getColumnConfigFromField(field);

                //Override with your values
                fieldConfig.width = 10;

                this.grid = this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    model: model,
                    columnCfgs: [
                        fieldConfig,  //pass your overridden formatted id field here
                        'Name',
                        'Owner'
                     ]  
                 });
             },
             scope: this
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: Great Kyle thanks.  BTW, it turns out it was not the width of this field that was the problem, but the fact that it was marked as a flex field.  Turning flex off gives me the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly differnt solution see: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345702/i-how-i-add-a-link-to-userstory-for-the-formattedid-column) for how to add the link back to your original try.