# Row editing does not seem to update the underlying store

Tags: javascript, rally

continuing with my app whose aim is to be able to edit an aggregated field and store the result of a computation on the various components of that aggregate in another field...

I am now able to properly retrieve my fields using an extension of the UserStory model, but I still cannot save my changes.
I am trying to check what's done in Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing's edit event, and I notice that when I reach it, e.store.data.items[rowIdx].data contains all my expected values, its dirty and editing flags are false, but e.store.data.items[rowIdx].raw does NOT reflect that (it contains the Rally's original values, unmodified) - even if I try to edit the value in raw, it does not work:

```
plugins: [
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        listeners: {
            'edit': function (editor, e) {
                e.store.data.items[e.rowIdx].raw.BusinessValues =
                    e.store.data.items[e.rowIdx].data.BusinessValues;

                e.store.commitChanges();
            }
        }
    })
]
```

Whole code follows, but I'm wondering if I should add a listener at model level instead?

```
Rally.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('BVApp', {
        extend: 'Rally.app.App',
        componentCls: 'app',
        launch: function() {
            Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
            type: 'UserStory',
            success: function(model) {
                var weights = new Array(5, 3, 1, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2);
                var BvTitles = new Array("Customers Impact", "Critical Path", "Usability", "Functionality", "Security", "Performance", "Integration", "Integrity", "Business Value");
                //var BvTitlesFrench = new Array("Parc Client", "Chemin Critique", "Ergonomie", "Fonctionnalité", "Sécurité", "Performance", "Intégration", "Intégrité", "Valeur Métier");

                // Thanks to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517383/sdk2-links-in-rally-grids-and-column-width I can now remove flex from FormattedID column...
                var fixedIDwithLink = Rally.ui.grid.FieldColumnFactory.getColumnConfigFromField( model.getField( 'FormattedID' ) );
                fixedIDwithLink.flex = false;
                fixedIDwithLink.width = 70;

                function getOneBV( record, pos, newValue ) {
                    var ls_BvFieldStart, ls_BvFieldEnd, ls_BvFromBvField;
                    if ( pos < 1 ) return newValue; // ERROR in fact...
                    if ( pos > 8 ) return newValue;
                    ls_BvFieldStart = record.data.BusinessValues.substring( 0, pos-1 );
                    ls_BvFromBvField = record.data.BusinessValues.substring( pos-1, pos );
                    ls_BvFieldEnd = record.data.BusinessValues.substring( pos, 8 );
                    if ( newValue ) {
                        ls_BvFromBvField = newValue;
                        record.data.BusinessValues = ls_BvFieldStart + ls_BvFromBvField + ls_BvFieldEnd;
                    }
                    return ls_BvFromBvField;
                }
                function getbv( as_bvHolder ) {
                    var li_bv1, li_bv2, li_bv3, li_bv4, li_bv5, li_bv6, li_bv7, li_bv8, li_bvtotal;
                    li_bv1 = as_bvHolder.substring( 0,1 );
                    li_bv2 = as_bvHolder.substring( 1,2 );
                    li_bv3 = as_bvHolder.substring( 2,3 );
                    li_bv4 = as_bvHolder.substring( 3,4 );
                    li_bv5 = as_bvHolder.substring( 4,5 );
                    li_bv6 = as_bvHolder.substring( 5,6 );
                    li_bv7 = as_bvHolder.substring( 7,8 );
                    li_bv8 = as_bvHolder.substring( 8,9 );
                    li_bvtotal =
                        li_bv1*weights[0] +
                        li_bv2*weights[1] +
                        li_bv3*weights[2] +
                        li_bv4*weights[3] +
                        li_bv5*weights[4] +
                        li_bv6*weights[5] +
                        li_bv7*weights[6] +
                        li_bv8*weights[7];
                    return li_bvtotal;
                }

                this.grid = this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallygrid',
                    model: Ext.define('BVModel', {
                        extend: model,
                        alias : 'BVModel',
                        fields: [
                            {name: 'Bv1', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 1, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'Bv2', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 2, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'Bv3', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 3, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'Bv4', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 4, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'Bv5', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 5, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'Bv6', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 6, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'Bv7', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 7, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'Bv8', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function(v, record){ return getOneBV( record, 8, v ); }
                            },
                            {name: 'BvTotal', type: 'string', persist: false,
                                convert: function( v, record ) {
                                    var ls_scoreInfo = '';
                                    if ( record.data.BusinessValues ) {
                                        ls_scoreInfo = getbv( record.data.BusinessValues ) + ' ';
                                    }
                                    if ( record.data.Score ) {
                                        ls_scoreInfo += '(previous: ' + record.data.Score + ')';
                                    }
                                    return ls_scoreInfo;
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }),
                        storeConfig: {
                            pageSize: 30, autoLoad: true, filters: [
                                {
                                    property: 'ScheduleState',
                                    operator: '=',
                                    value: 'Backlog'
                                }
                                //,{ property: 'FormattedID', value: 'US85792' } // US85792, US84529, US81387, US77032
                            ],
                            context: this.getContext().getDataContext()
                        },
                    columnCfgs: [
                        fixedIDwithLink, // might want to add a select listener later to display details in a child pane ?
                        'Name',
                        'BusinessValues',
                        'AffectedCustomers',
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[0], dataIndex: 'Bv1', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[1], dataIndex: 'Bv2', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[2], dataIndex: 'Bv3', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[3], dataIndex: 'Bv4', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[4], dataIndex: 'Bv5', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[5], dataIndex: 'Bv6', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[6], dataIndex: 'Bv7', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[7], dataIndex: 'Bv8', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }, width: 70
                        },
                        {
                            text: BvTitles[8], dataIndex: 'BvTotal', editor: { xtype: 'textfield' }
                        }
                    ],
                    selType: 'rowmodel',
                    plugins: [
                        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
                            clicksToEdit: 1,
                            listeners: {
                                'edit': function (editor, e) {
                                    e.store.data.items[e.rowIdx].raw.BusinessValues = e.store.data.items[e.rowIdx].data.BusinessValues;
                                    e.store.commitChanges();
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    ]
                });

                }, // end of getModel success
                scope: this
            });
        }
    });

    Rally.launchApp('BVApp', {
        name: 'Business Values App'
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the get & set functions of the record object to retrieve and change the data instead of digging into the "data" or "raw" fields. This way, the Ext library can manage the changes better to update the store/records properly.

So, when you want to get the value of the "BusinessValues" field, use `record.get('BusinessValues')`. Likewise, try `record.set('BusinessValues', newValue)` to set the new value in the getOneBV function. In doing this, you might be able to comment out the RowEditing plugin you added.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - Unfortunately this does not seem to change anything to the actual record.
Also I wonder how I could comment out the RowEditing plugin because if I don't keep it, I can't edit the line,... or how could I?